# Можно ли в Php получить имя поля?

Tags: php

Есть несколько полей:

```
<input type="file" name="file1" />
<input type="file" name="file2" />
<input type="file" name="file3" />
```

Можно ли в php получить их тэг name? И как?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда Вы отправите это форму на сервер, у Вас будет массив `$_FILES`, в котором ключами будут эти три (или сколько их) поля, а значениями - данные о загруженных файлах.

Вот Ваша форма:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<input type="file" name="file1" />
<input type="file" name="file2" />
<input type="file" name="file3" />
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

В `file2` я заношу PNG файл и отправляю. В переменной `$_FILES` получаю

```
array(3) {
  ["file1"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["type"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["error"]=>
    int(4)
    ["size"]=>
    int(0)
  }
  ["file2"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(12) "download.png"
    ["type"]=>
    string(9) "image/png"
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(14) "/tmp/phpVvZcNz"
    ["error"]=>
    int(0)
    ["size"]=>
    int(336)
  }
  ["file3"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["type"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["error"]=>
    int(4)
    ["size"]=>
    int(0)
  }
}
```

Comment: а как получить то эту переменную? $_FILES[0] не работает.. Мне нужно переменную в foreach вывести эту

Comment: А ее не надо получать. Она есть. Это как `$_POST`, `$_GET`, `$_REQUEST`. (http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.php) Если Вы отправляете на сервер форму, в которой `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, то переменная `$_FILES` будет. Однако обратите внимание, что это АССОЦИАТИВНЫЙ массив. Т.е.  надо не `$_FILES[0]`, а `foreach($_FILES as $field=>$fieldData){`

Comment: Если так делаю field показывает 0, а fieldData показывает Сам ключ, но само содержание исчезает

Comment: значит что-то не так делаете... Убедитесь, что enctype стоит правильно, что форма post... Попробуйте `var_dump($_FILES)`, посмотрите содержимое...